# Error de segmentación al cargar el modelo PyTorch en la aplicación

Tags: python, python-3.x, manejo-de-memoria, out-of-memory-error, pytorch

Estoy experimentando un problema al cargar un modelo PyTorch en una aplicación que estoy desarrollando desde una máquina virtual. He creado una instancia del modelo utilizando la misma ruta de archivo que funciona correctamente en un script independiente, pero cuando intento cargarlo desde mi aplicación, obtengo un error de segmentación.

Aqui es el codigo de un archivo `test.py` sobre una maquina virtual:

```
model = UC_Model(pModel_filepath="/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_La_Organisacion_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra")
print("model: ", model)
```

El modelo se carga normalmente:

```
model:  <UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection.UC_Model object at 0x7f687d869a00>
```

Pero cuando lo hago desde la aplicación que estoy desarrollando, me aparece el siguiente problema:

```
   .create Model from '/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_La_Organisacion_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra'
./kaa.sh: line 48: 1870463 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 kaa.py $1
```

Así que estoy en la misma máquina virtual.

Aquí está el código de la aplicación que he creado para cargar el modelo desde el archivo :

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Launch the inference computation
# @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
# @return parameter dictionary updated
def launchInference(pDictParams):
    TUI.TUIprint("Action: Inference","Action")

    # create the model instance
    if has_method(pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'],'UCXAI_createModel'):
        print("pDictParams['pluginUCXAI']: ", pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'])
        aiModel=pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'].UCXAI_createModel(pDictParams)
```

En `pDictParams['pluginUCXAI']` tenemos una instanciacion de una classe, `UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection_Xplique`:

```
import UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Class for Use case vs Library
class UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection_Xplique(kaasrc.plugin_collection.Plugin):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Class constructor
    # @param self : l'instance de la classe
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.nom = "UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection"
        self.description = "Detect bad vibrations in time series"
        self.modeles = ["PerceiverLogit"]
        self.bibliotheque = "Xplique"
        self.methodes = ["Hsic","Occlusion","KernelShap","Rise","Lime","Sobol"]
        self.metriques = None
        self.UC=UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Create an instance of the model
    # @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
    # @return the instance of the model
    # @remark Call directly UC_createModel() of UC model
    def UCXAI_createModel(self,pDictParams):
        return self.UC.UC_createModel(pDictParams)
```

Y UC.UC_createModel(pDictParams) esta:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Create an instance of the model
# @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
# @return the instance of the model
def UC_createModel(pDictParams):
    # shortcuts
    pModelBase=pDictParams['modelBase']
    pModelpath=pDictParams['modelpath']
    pModelfile=pDictParams['modelfile']
    pCode=pDictParams['code']

    # get model file
    ficModel=os.path.join(pModelBase,pModelpath,pModelfile)
    print("   .create Model from '%s'"%ficModel,flush=True)

    # create model instance from 'model' parameter
    aiModel=UC_Model(ficModel)
    print("      ",aiModel.name,"-/-",pCode,flush=True)
```

Y pienso que el core dump arriva con `aiModel=UC_Model(ficModel)`.

Creo que debe ser un problema de la tarjeta gráfica. Siempre tomo CUDA=0 en la aplicación